# Zend Soap Server return an UTF-8 error

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I'm using Zend Soap Server with autodiscover, this is my code:

```
    $wsdl = new Zend_Soap_Autodiscover();
    $wsdl->setClass('SoapParser');
    if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
        $wsdl->handle();
    } else {
    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server('http://zzz.zz.zz/store.php?wsdl');
    $server->setClass('SoapParser');

    $server->setEncoding('UTF-8');
    $server->setObject(new SoapParser());
    $server->handle();
    }
```

When I invoke some methods through a SOAP client, I receive this error:

SOAP-ENV:ServerSOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '00127920110531 xxx zzz Dom 67 av Ren\xe9...' is not a valid utf-8 string

the "\xe9" is a "é"... source table is in UTF-8

if I change

```
      $server->setEncoding('UTF-8');
```

in

```
      $server->setEncoding('ISO-8859-1')
```

i don't receive the error but the strings aren't correctly parsed, there are stranges chars...

Any idea?

Comment: `0xe9` is a `é` in `ISO-8859-1`, not `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with your server, this is a problem with your client.

Your client is submitting an `ISO-8859-1` string, you may try to `utf8_encode()` the data prior to submitting it.

If you still see weird chars when both the client and the server use the same encoding, then you might have a source string mixing several encodings. Is it built from a single source? Is it being displayed correctly somewhere?

Comment: You are right, the problem was in the client (a third part client). I tried with zend_client and it works fine. Thx